# How do I create a function to decrypt the encrypted file?

Tags: c, file, pdf, encryption

I'm trying to get the basics of some weak encryption but I'm at a wall....I need a function to call that will decrypt the encrypted file.  But my main question is how do i go about decrypting this file?  Please be nice I'm new to this! =]
Also, the w.pdf file starts as a regular pdf inside the project folder, and I do have error checking in the program just excluded it here for the sake of saving space.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *ptr1,*file,*ptr3;
    unsigned long key;
    int B,C;

    ptr1=fopen("w.pdf","rb");
    file=fopen("encryptFile.pdf","wb");

    printf("Enter the encrypt key: ");
    scanf("%ld",&key);

    //Transfer contents
    while((B=fgetc(ptr1))!=EOF)
        fputc(C=B^(key & 0xff), file);
    key=key^C;
    puts("\nencryptFile.pdf has finished.");

    rewind(file);

    ptr3=fopen("new.pdf","wb");

    //pdf file closing.
    fclose(ptr1);
    fclose(file);
    fclose(ptr3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, so you are new, so I'll be nicer than I have been lately.  Please don't write any more code at all until you know how to use a debugger.  That is an essential skill and you cannot develop software without it.  Niceness enhanced - no downvote and no closevote.  Most posters who show no edvidence of debugging attempts, and info aquired thereby, get auto-downCloseVoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries, everyone starts somewhere. (But you should probably start with Google, wikipedia, or [a lesson](http://learncryptography.com/encryption/) rather than starting out asking on StackOverflow)

Your encryption scheme is to `xor` the content with a key the user entered.

To decrypt the content, you'd have to reverse the encryption, which in this case is just `xor`ing the content with the key again.

Some other helpful advice:

- Indent your code, it'll go a long way towards making it readable
- Name your variables better. `ptr1` could be `encryptionTarget`, `clearText`, or `f_pdfFile`

Comment: Thank you....that is all I needed to know is how to reverse the encryption, perfect answer and helpful!